# Intuitive Understanding of Second Derivative/Concavity.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In Calculus, I understand that derivatives (simply explained) are a rate of change; a slope of a function at a certain point. However, I am struggling to understand the explanations behind the second derivative, or even bigger derivatives.

The second derivative is the rate of change of a rate of change. As we continue to take the derivative of a large polynomial (ie. x^50+x^20), the exponents drop out and we are, eventually, left with a constant. So what is the relationship between the the final derivative and the original function? For example, What is exactly happening when there is a
f^(10)(x) = 4 ? How do all x's on the function relate to the same number?

If I may ask another somewhat related question, what exactly is concavity and its relationship to f'(x)? My textbook explains upward and downward concavity happening when f lies above/below all of its tangents on an interval I. 
What does the f lying above and below all of its tangent exactly have to do with concavity? How is this showing a change in the first derivative? In other words, what is the relationship between f'(x) and f"(x) when we are looking at a concavity?

Comment: Suppose that the distance you run in a car is expressed as a function of time $$\text{distance}=f(t)$$ The first derivative expresses how the speed of the car varies with time $$\text{speed}=f'(t)$$  The second derivative expresses how the acceleration of the car varies with time $$\text{acceleration}=f''(t)$$ and so on.

Comment: This might help for your second question: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Convex_Real_Function (posed in terms of convex, but the case is symmetric for concave).

Also, convince yourself that when the function is twice differentiable, the derivative definition and those above are equivalent.